# Keras Combining Batches Of Single Image After Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using an autoencoder to denoise gray-scale images of high resolution. Each image is divided into sub-batches of a particular size i.e `52 x 52`  and the model works on each of these batches then the result is the concatenation of the denoised batches in each image back to the original one. Below is an example of an image after the result:

[image: Batches Denoised]

You can see the smaller image batches after concatenation. How to overcome this behavior?

I thought about doing further processing like adding blur to the edges to blend them together, however I think this is not the optimal solution.

code of concatenation:

```
num_hor_patch = 19
num_ver_patch = 26

print("Building the Images Batches")
for i in range(num_image):
    reconstruct = []
    for j in range(num_hor_patch):
        from_vertical_patches = predictions[start_pos:(start_pos+num_ver_patch)]
        horizontal_patch = np.concatenate(from_vertical_patches, axis=1)
        start_pos += num_ver_patch
        reconstruct.append(horizontal_patch)

    restored_image = np.concatenate(np.array(reconstruct), axis=0)
    output.append(restored_image)

start_pos = 0
test_data = np.array([np.reshape(test_data[i], (52, 52)) for i in range(test_data.shape[0])])
for i in range(num_image):
    reconstruct = []
    for j in range(num_hor_patch):
        from_vertical_patches = test_data[start_pos:(start_pos+num_ver_patch)]
        horizontal_patch = np.concatenate(from_vertical_patches, axis=1)
        start_pos += num_ver_patch
        reconstruct.append(horizontal_patch)

    restored_image = np.concatenate(np.array(reconstruct), axis=0)
    input.append(restored_image)

start_pos = 0
test_noisy_data = np.array([np.reshape(test_noisy_data[i], (52, 52)) for i in range(test_noisy_data.shape[0])])
for i in range(num_image):
    reconstruct = []
    for j in range(num_hor_patch):
        from_vertical_patches = test_noisy_data[start_pos:(start_pos+num_ver_patch)]
        horizontal_patch = np.concatenate(from_vertical_patches, axis=1)
        start_pos += num_ver_patch
        reconstruct.append(horizontal_patch)

    restored_image = np.concatenate(np.array(reconstruct), axis=0)
    noisy.append(restored_image)

print("Exporting the Model")
output_model['output'] = output
output_model['original'] = input
output_model['noisy'] = noisy
```

Comment: Hi there! Why are you not passing the whole image into the Autoencoder at once and get the result? It should improve your inference time as well. Additionally, sticking to your current approach you can follow this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RishabP. Unfortunately the images won't fit into the memory available. If there is another solution you would recommend that will make it possible, Answer the question with it!

Answer (score 1):

From the image looks like you are dealing with ~400x800 resolution images. For this the 16GB-32GB memory of V100 GPUs should be enough for a decent batch sizes with a decent model capacity! Even if not, then you can trim down the memory utilization by a factor of 2 to 4 using mixed-precision or even fp16.

If your resolution is too high to play these tricks, then ideally you need to implement a model parallelism approach by splitting the image patches on GPUs (spatial partitioning), and exchanging the tensors between these domains in the computational graph during forward and backward passes. This will make the patches consistent, but may result in significant performance bottlenecks!

You can take a look at this UNET architecture which you will have to convert from Conv3D to Conv2D and switch from segmentation to de-noising task.

https://github.com/tensorflow/mesh/blob/master/mesh_tensorflow/experimental/unet.py

Comment: will try the latter solution. I am dealing with images of min 1000x1000 gray scale. I only cropped a portion to make it clear

Comment: You may have to use TPU cores in GCP for this architecture. They don’t explain very well how to run this on GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

So correct me if i am wrong but you have the following problem:

- Denoise autoencoder which get a 52x52 images
- An image with size HxW where W >> 52 and H >> 52

and the question is how to use the autoencoder to denoise the image?

Your current solution is:

1. divide the image to **non-overlap** tiles
2. For each tile denoise with the autoencoder
3. Concatenate the resulted denoised tiles to form the original image

This solution gives very non consistence result in the seam between the tiles.

I think you need to use an **overlapping** tiles and not **non-overlap** tiles.

This means that each pixel is part of several tiles and not just one.
And therefor will have several denoised values, one from each tile that he his a part of.

The final value for each pixel will be the mean of the values from all the tiles that the pixel is part of.

The new solution:

1. divide the image to **overlapping** tiles (More tiles the smother result)
2. For each tile denoise with the autoencoder
3. For each pixel in the final image take the mean value from all the tiles the pixel is part of.

Comment: Can you please tell how do you make sure that getting the mean value of the pixel from the overlapping tiles would result in a smooth transition along the images border? Can you provide a very simple example on an image of size 200x200.

Comment: I can't make sure it will make it smother but it think because every pixel will participate in several tiles it will be more connected to it's nigbhors and sorry but i can't provide an example.